# Iframe load event inside an AngularJs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, iframe, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a directive so that I can do some element manipulation upon the load of an iFrame inside of an ng-repeat.

The below CodePen contains an iframe both inside and outside of an ng-repeat. The directive initializes without a problem but the load events never fire.

```
var app = angular.module('tester', []);

app.directive('iframeOnload', [function(){
return {
    scope: {
        callBack: '&iframeOnload'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      alert("Directive Init")
        element.on('load', function(){
          alert("Load Event Fired")
            return scope.callBack();
        })
    }
}}])

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {    

  $scope.tester1 = function (){
    alert("Testing 1")
  }

  $scope.tester2 = function (){
    alert("Testing 2")
  }

  $scope.theTemplate = [
            {
                Id: 1,                
                ElementId: 99,                                      
                Content: 'Element1',
                ElementHeight: 130,              
            },
            {
                Id: 2,
                ElementId: 98,                                      
                Content: 'Element2',
                ElementHeight: 320,              
            },
            {
                Id: 3,
                ElementId: 2,                                      
                Content: 'Element3',
                ElementHeight: 320,
            }];
});
```

.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <iframe iframe-onload="tester2()"></iframe>
  <ul>    
    <li ng-repeat="element in theTemplate" id="li_{{element.Id}}"  style="position: relative; height:{{element.ElementHeight}}px;">
      <iframe iframe-onload="tester1()" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height:{{element.ElementHeight}}px;" id="iframeElement{{element.Id}}"></iframe>
      {{element.Content}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  </body>
```

https://codepen.io/jibber4568/pen/agZxgP

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use angular element ready method for that. Try the following please.

```
app.directive('iframeOnload', [function(){
return {
    scope: {
        callBack: '&iframeOnload'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      alert("Directive Init")
        element.ready(function(){
          alert("Load Event Fired")
            return scope.callBack();
        })
    }
}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is due to the fact that you are not using jQuery, therefore AngularJs uses it's own jqLite, from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

> on() - Does not support namespaces, selectors or eventData

You can use the native `addEventListener` on the **DOM node**, so your link function will like that:

```
link: function (scope, $element, attrs) {
  console.log('Directive Init');
  var element = $element[0];
  element.addEventListener('load', function () {
    console.log('Load Event Fired');
    return scope.callBack();
  }, { once: true });
}
```